# Remplazar caracteres de un string en python usando Listas

Tags: python, loops, if, else

Buenas! Intento hacer que mi script recorra toda un `string` y vaya remplazando cada carácter con el de otro `string` utilizando listas para poder cambiar cada uno de los caracteres de una manera mas sencilla, pero al recorrer mi lista no los reemplaza porque los limita el rango del ciclo, ¿hay una función que me permita reemplazar todos los caracteres de una lista por otros `string` o debería poner dos ciclos en el código de la misma manera?

```
lock = ("plmnkoijbvhuygcxfteszaqw")
key = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
toWrite = list("eola")

x = 0
y = 0

  for i  in range(len(toWrite)):
    if toWrite[x] == key[y]:
        toWrite[x] = lock[y]
        x = x + 1
    else:
      y = y + 1


print(toWrite)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los string `key` y `luck` han de tener el mismo numero de elementos, ya que cada valor de `key` ha de ser intercambiado por el correspondiente de `luck`.

Corrigiendo lo anterior (he añadido "d" y "r" al string `lock`), puedes usar [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) para lo que quieres, creando una tabla con los reemplazos usando [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
lock = "plmnkoijbvhuygcxfteszaqwdr"
key  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
trantab = str.maketrans(key, lock)

toWrite = "eola"
print(toWrite.translate(trantab))
```

Si por alguna razón no quieres usar `str.translate` una buena opción es usar un diccionario para crear la tabla de traducciones, será mucho más eficiente que usar indexado:

```
lock = "plmnkoijbvhuygcxfteszaqwdr"
key  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
toWrite = "eola"
trantab = {key: value for key, value  in zip(key, lock)}
toWrite = "".join(trantab.get(c, c) for c in toWrite)
print(toWrite)
```

`transtab` en este caso es un diccionario de la forma:

```
{'a': 'p', 'b': 'l', 'c': 'm', ...}
```

Para cada clave (carácter a substituir) tenemos un valor (carácter que sustituye). El método `dict.get` retorna el valor de cada clave pasada como primer argumento, si no existe la clave en el diccionario retorna lo que pasemos como segundo elemento (en este caso el carácter del string original).

En ambos casos las tablas de traducciones son reutilizables, lo cual es importante si vas a aplicarla sobre múltiples cadenas.

La salida es:

> kcup

---

He presupuesto que usas Python 3 ya que no usas la etiqueta para Python 2, no obstante si se quiere usar `translate` en Python 2 simplemente importamos
`maketrans` de la biblioteca `string`:

```
from string import maketrans

lock = "plmnkoijbvhuygcxfteszaqwdr"
key  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
trantab = maketrans(key, lock)

toWrite = "eola"
print(toWrite.translate(trantab))
```

Comment: Si quiero agregarle un simple espacio(" ") a la cadena toWrite no me dará error?

Comment: No, cualquier carácter que no esté en la tabla simplemente no se sustituye. Por ejemplo, `toWrite = "¡hola mundo!` retornará `¡jcup yzgnc!`. ¿Es a esto a lo que te refieres? Por supuesto que puedes hacer que el espacio también se sustituya por otro carácter, o incluso que sea eliminado.