# Error "IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename" al crear archivo csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows, archivo, pandas

Necesito convertir este código de Python que uso en MAC a alguno que pueda usar en Windows 10 con la misma versión de Python (2.7).

Básicamente abro un csv y lo cargo en un DataFrame, agrupo por una de las columnas y creo un nuevo csv por cada grupo, tomando el nombre de cada csv de salida de la columna sobre la que aplico `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("All_Data_Tags.csv",  header=0,  sep = ",")
for group in df.groupby(df["trafficChannel"]):
    group[1].to_csv("{}.csv".format(group[0]), sep=',', index=False)
```

En Mac lo corro sin problemas pero en Windows me salta este error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: '152 Media DK $ 2 | 09-11-17.csv

Comment: Puedes compartir el archivo zippeado para analizarlo

Comment: El carácter `|` no esta permitido en Windows en un nombre de archivo, tampoco`/`, `\\``, `:` , `?`,  `*`, `<`, `>` ni `"` si no me dejo alguno. Como obtienes los nombres del csv vas a tener que cambiar cualquier de esos caracteres por otros válidos.

Comment: sabes como puedo omitir esa barra?? Necesito poder hacerlo si o si, digo que busque en todo el csv esa barra y la borre. Si puedes abrir un chat necesito comentarte algo que tambien me paso con el csv del codigo que hablamos hoy... @FJSevilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene dado por que los caracteres `|`, `/`, `\`, `:` , `?`, `*`, `<`, `>` y `"` son [caracteres reservados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) no permitidos en el nombre de archivos/ficheros en Windows.

Dado que obtienes los nombres de una columna de tu csv, la solución que te queda es remplazar el carácter no permitido, en este caso "|" por otro que no presente ese problema.

Para ello puedes usar el método [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) que aplica el reemplazo de forma vectorizada sobre la columna:

```
import pandas as pd

dat = {"trafficChannel": ['152 Media DK $ 2 | 09-11-17',
                          '153 Media DK $ 2 | 09-11-17']
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
df["trafficChannel"] = df["trafficChannel"].str.replace("|", "%")
```

Usa el carácter que quieras de reemplazo, o una cadena vacía para eliminarlos completamente. En este caso se cambia por `%`:

```
>>> df

                 trafficChannel
0   152 Media DK $ 2 % 09-11-17
1   153 Media DK $ 2 % 09-11-17
```

En tu caso simplemente puedes hacer:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("All_Data_Tags.csv",  header=0,  sep = ",")
df["trafficChannel"] = df["trafficChannel"].str.replace("|", "%")
for group in df.groupby(df["trafficChannel"]):
    group[1].to_csv("{}.csv".format(group[0]), sep=',', index=False)
```

Se podrían sustituir diferentes caracteres de una vez si crees posible que existan otros caracteres no válidos en la columna.

Otra opción es aplicar `str.replace` en cada iteración del `for`:

```
for group in df.groupby(df["trafficChannel"]):
    group[1].to_csv("{}.csv".format(group[0].replace("|", "%")),
                    sep=',', index=False)
```

en este caso para múltiples reemplazos se puede usar [`str.translate`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/120415/15089).

Comment: como puedo armarlo al codigo? necesito que levante los datos desde mi csv:
`import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("All_Data_Tags.csv",  header=0,  sep = ",")
for group in df.groupby(df["trafficChannel"]):
    group[1].to_csv("{}.csv".format(group[0]), sep=',', index=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
df["trafficChannel"] = df["trafficChannel"].str.replace("|", "%")`

Comment: podrias unir mi codigo que esta en la rpegunta con el que me respondiste? @FJSevilla

Comment: Añade `df["trafficChannel"] = df["trafficChannel"].str.replace("|", "%")` antes de la línea del `for` con `groupby` si solo tienes ese carácter inválido no debes tener problemas.